# MYSQL SELECT INTO with awswrangler library

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds, aws-sdk, amazon-aurora

I am trying to run an INSERT INTO query to perform UPSERT on a table on a MySQL database managed by RDS.
This is the python code I wrote to perform the operation:

```
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

insert_into_query = """
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES (21, 'Bishop', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    CustomerID=VALUES(CustomerID),
    CustomerID = VALUES(CustomerId),
    CustomerName = VALUES(CustomerName),
    ContactName = VALUES(ContactName),
    Address = VALUES(Address),
    City = VALUES(City),
    PostalCode = VALUES(PostalCode),
    Country = VALUES(Country)
"""
;

con = wr.mysql.connect(secret_id=secret_id, dbname = dbname)
with con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(insert_into_query)
```

When I try to read the data with the code below,

```
df = wr.mysql.read_sql_query(
    sql=f"SELECT * FROM {dbname}.Customers",
    con=con
)
```

The *Customer* table has been created with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CustomerName varchar(255),
    ContactName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PostalCode varchar(255),
    Country varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
)
;
```

I can see that if I change the CustomerID, the value is overwritten and no new rows are appended.
Why is that?

I understand that the problem could be solved by using the `awswrangler.mysql.to_sql`method with the `mode` parameter set to `'upsert_duplicate_key'`, however I would like to know if it is possible to run `INSERT INTO` queries with the `wr.mysql.connect` method.

Thanks

### Edit:

The following changes have fixed the issue:

1. replace

```
VALUES(21, 'Bishop', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway')
```

with

```
VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

2. Remove `CustomerID=VALUES(CustomerID)`
3. Add values to `execute` method like so:

```
cursor.execute(insert_into_query, (21, 'Bishop', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway'))
```

Comment: ' CustomerID, the value is overwritten and no new rows are appended. Why is that?' -  I don't think so you are setting customerid to itself. If you wanted to update customerid then the set statement would include values(customerid). Also you need a set to include every column to update.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon, I forgot to add the lines that update the other fields. I have amended the question. However, I still get the same behaviour. Data is overwritten even if the CustomerID changes.

Comment: Not with you. Behaviour is as expected  - every column in the set statement will change if a duplicate is detected. If you only want to change columns other than customerid then you should not be setting customerid. If no duplicate is detected then an insert will occur. I think you need to spend some time with the manual.

Comment: I am running the exact same queries from mysql workbench and I am getting the desired output. If I change the CustomerID, a new row is created, otherwise, if there was a change in the field, it will be captured, otherwise it will return the same unchanged output. Apologies if I can't be clearer.

Comment: I don't see a commit.

Comment: apologies what do you mean?

Comment: "When I try to read the data with the code below": what happens? you didn't finish the sentence. Also please post the relevant contents of your table. Thank you.

Comment: @Quassnoi the snippet is visible to me...I have found the issue, I need to pass the values with the placeholder %s in the VALUES function. Now the scripts return the expected outputs. I have tried using pymysql too and behaviour is the same as the one returned from awswrangler.mysql.